# Typesetting statement of purpose for a masters application

Tags: masters, application, application-cover-letter

What is a good format to use for the statement of purpose on a masters application?  I read that margins should be 1 inch (2.54cm). This seems to leave quite a lot of space on the page though. Should I use the justify feature on word? I used this often when writing mathematical coursework, as a lot of my lecturers also used it in their lecture notes, but is it suitable/needed in this case?

The main things I'd like to know:

- Font
- Margin size
- Use justify or not
- Spacing

Note: by format, I don't mean the structure of content, I mean the aesthetics of the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow the instructions. Absent any such guidelines, you can do whatever you like, within reason. In the US, "reasonable" tends to mean:

- Times New Roman, Arial, Calibri, or something similar
- Single spaced, or something close to that (e.g., 1.1)
- 1" margins, almost always
- Left or justified alignment, personal preference
- Indent your paragraphs or leave a space between paragraphs or both
- Header on each page including your name, page number, and any other relevant information you'd like to include. (e.g., university name, application number)

Personally, I like to use letterhead (either institutional or with my name on it) for official documents like this.